# How to animate 3D line plotting?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

While there are some tutorials about matplotlib animation, I am still confused about how to update animation function in this case:

```
pointA = np.array([[pAx1, pAx2, pAx3, ...],
                   [pAy1, pAy2, pAy3, ...],
                   [pAz1, pAz2, pAz3, ...]])

pointB = np.array([[pBx1, pBx2, pBx3, ...],
                   [pBy1, pBy2, pBy3, ...],
                   [pBz1, pBz2, pBz3, ...]])
```

The animation would be plotting a sequence of line connected by pointA and pointB, for example:

```
ax.plot([pAx1,pBx1], [pAy1,pBy1], [pAz1,pBz1])
ax.plot([pAx2,pBx2], [pAy2,pBy2], [pAz2,pBz2])
```